# How to use NSURLSession to upload image to server

Tags: php, json, nsurlsession, ios9

With iOS 9, I was forced to change my old NSURLConnection with NSURLSession. I had a working code to upload an image from my phone to my server, with a piece of php code to store the image.
There are plenty of nice tutorials out there, like this one: http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

```
// 1
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/insertImage.php"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

// 2
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// 3
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1": @"value1"};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary 
  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (!error) {
 // 4
 NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
   fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
   // Handle response here
   }];

   // 5
   [uploadTask resume];
}
```

This seems pretty simple and nice, but I have some problems. 
How do I embedd an image into this code?
How do I change the name of the image? 
Which delegats do I need? 
and most importantly, 
How does the server side look like?
I simply just want to store the image in a folder named "uploads".